# flow complains if when having react and react-native in node_modules

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

When `react-native` and `react` is in the `./node_modules`, `flow` will complain a "duplicate provider module error".

I'm using `module.system = haste` in my `.flowconfig`.

Is there a workaround without making flow to ignore one of them?

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to add one of them to the [ignore] section of your .flowconfig